# Google apps script running on a Google Site is slowwww

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to figure out why the following, fairly simple script is running so slowly. It just opens a Google sheet reads less that 10 rows of data and displays on a Google site. The script takes 20+ seconds to run. TIA.

```
function doGet() {
  var sOutput = "";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1sUnNnqmFM120Qa9ZWFvJQ6TLfM0V51Kj4zA");

  var data = ss.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues();

  for (var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {

    sOutput = sOutput + data[j] + '<br>';


  }
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(sOutput);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
data[j]
```

To:

```
data[j].toString();
```

The `getValues()` method returns a 2D array.  When you use `data[j]`, it's not getting data, it getting an inner array of data.

I think what is happening, is that HTML Service is converting the 1D array to text, but it's taking longer than if the value is not an array.   When you use `data[j]`, it's not getting text, it's getting the **inner array**.  That inner array need to be converted to text, but if you do that "up front" maybe it will make a difference.  Just a guess.

Try changing this:

```
var data = ss.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues();
```

To:

```
var sh = ss.getSheetByName(name);
var data = sh.getRange(1, 1, sh.getLastRow(), sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried your code by execution time is still 20+ seconds.

Comment: Updated answer with another suggestion.

Comment: In case you saw the update real quick, I changed it again.

Comment: Still slow. Is there anyway to profile the code? I look at the execution transcript but it does not tell me much in the way of each steps execution time. I really can't tell what is causing the script to run so long. Thanks.

Comment: You could add `Logger.log("myVariable: " + myVariable)` statements, and that way you'd get a time stamp for every iteration of the `for` loop.  And a timestamp after every variable assignment.  Then VIEW the LOG.